# Why some tensorflow whls are extremely lightweight?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why some `tensorflow` whls are [extremely lightweight](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.15.0/#files)?

`tensorflow-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl` is 2.1 kB
`tensorflow-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl` is 475.3 MB
`tensorflow-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl` is 2.2 kB
`tensorflow-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl` is 2.1 kB
`tensorflow-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl` is 239.1 MB

Why some of them are 200+ and 400+ MBs, and some of them are just kBs?
I use tensorflow on Windows and install tiny whl. Everything works just interesting why such a difference is.

Answer (score 0):

> Why some tensorflow whls are extremely lightweight?

The variation in size among TensorFlow wheels (wheels) can be attributed to a multitude of factors:

**TensorFlow version and build configuration:** Newer versions of TensorFlow may include additional features,bug fixes,or optimizations, or bug fixes, which can affect the size of the wheel. Additionally, the build configuration
Distribution method and packaging: Some of the wheels have included various additional resources or documentation, which can increase their size.

**Architecture and platform-specific optimizations:-**
The size of the wheel is contingent upon the target platform and architecture. For instance, wheels designated for manylinux_2_17_x86_64 and manylinux_2_17_aarch64 are tailored for distinct Linux distributions and architectures. These wheels incorporate precompiled binaries optimized for specific hardware architectures, potentially leading to larger file sizes in comparison to generic wheels.

**Included dependencies and libraries:** TensorFlow has dependencies on various libraries such as CUDA, cuDNN, and others for GPU support. If these dependencies are bundled within the wheel, it can significantly increase the size of the wheel.